# Is it possible to make this kind of grid like texture and how?

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-painting

Can anyone give me some advice on how will I be able to achieve this kind of grid like (generated from the horizontal and vertical line) texture? It doesn't have to be exactly the same but relatively similar and better if it's not a clean straight line.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: @JachymMichal Hi, I just don't know how to approach this texture atm. Do you have any suggestions? I have only dealt with image texture and some tutorial procedural texture. I need to overlay this texture onto my procedural texture as well. Sorry I'm still quite new to blender.

Comment: Hey :). The easiest way is to make the pattern in Illustrator/Photoshop and just tile it. If you're looking for a procedural solution, *Brick texture* looks like a good place to start.